# simple setup for a local area with 4 vlans

Tags: windows-7, linux, windows

I need to set up 2 lan ports on my pfsense to each be a member of 4 vlans (10,20,30,40) with each vlan having a separate gateway ( 10.10.1.1, 10.20.1.1, 10.30.1.1 and 10.40.1.1).  I would like hosts connected to each of these 2 ports to be able to communicate with each other over the vlan20.

Host A -Linux- has a nic set with 4 virtual ip addresses (10.10.1.10 Vlan10, 10.20.1.10vlan20, 10.30.1.10vlan30, and 10.40.1.10vlan40) Needs 3 vlans to talk to itself and 4th to communicate with host B over vlan20

Host B -windows- has a nic set with 10.20.1.110 /24 gw-10.20.1.1

Comment: I tried and cant seem to get it right... I've reset to defaults so that i can start from scratch.  pfsense 2.3.1